# How to merge two tags in SASS (or pure CSS)?

Tags: css, sass

I would like to have the usual "monospace on gray background" rendering for elements of code in my document. The HTML document is rendered from Markdown and can be of three kinds:

````
This is the markdown version with some `inline code`. The block code can be either like this

```
for i in world:
    say(i)
```

or the SO way like that

    for i in world:
        say(i)

back to normal text
````

This is rendered to

```css
code {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  background: lightgray;
}

pre {
  background: lightgray;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is the markdown version with some <code>inline code</code>. The block code can be either like this</p>

<pre>
<code>for i in world:
    say(i)
</code>
</pre>
<p>or the SO way like that</p>

<pre>
<code>for i in world:
    say(i)
</code>
</pre>

<p>back to normal text</p>
```

The part I wonder about is the CSS. It works fine as it is now but I feel that this is not the correct (recommended) way to address the fact that

- `<code>` can be inline or in a block, so it should I believe carry the `background` option
- if I leave out `background` in `pre` I end up with distinct gray lines, one for each line of code.

It is probably the repetition which bothers me most but it might be very well that this is the right way to do it. I am learning SASS so either this or CSS recommendations are OK with me.

Comment: I think  for code tag no need the background because it is already assigned in the parent of the element

Answer (score 0):

Merging two tags in CSS:

```
pre, code {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

But I guess you already know it. Solves the repetition tho.

Comment: yes, but then I need an extra `pre` entry only for the `padding` then?

Comment: I'd go with this approach as well, yes. Seems the most clean one if you're **certain** that `pre` and `code` will always be `lightgray`

Comment: It all comes to kind of 'your coding way'. You are going to either group by tags or by properties (while leaving usage of classes aside).

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
pre{
  background: lightgray;
  padding-left: 30px;
  code{
      font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  }
}
```